# cannot install blackberry webworks plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, cordova, eclipse-plugin

using http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java ,I installed Blackberry java plugin(core),Blackberry java SDK but for using phonegap, i used this as reference

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks

i tried  http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web to get the blackberry webworks plugin,webworks SDK but was not successful, It gave error

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

Software being installed: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2(net.rim.browser.tools.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.201010291444-2)

Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.1.20110909-1818 (epp.package.jee 1.4.1.20110909-1818)

Only one of the following can be installed at once:

```
Views 3.5.0.I20100527-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.views 3.5.0.I20100527-0800)
Views 3.5.1.M20110202-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.views 3.5.1.M20110202-0800)
Views 3.6.0.I20110412-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.views 3.6.0.I20110412-0800)
Views 3.6.0.v20110928-1505 (org.eclipse.ui.views 3.6.0.v20110928-1505)
```

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.1.20110909-1818 (epp.package.jee1.4.1.20110909-1818)

To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.4.1.20110909-1818]

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 (net.rim.browser.tools.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.201010291444-2)

To: net.rim.browser.tools.widget [2.5.1.201010291444-2]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: BlackBerry WebWorks Plug-in 2.5.1.201010291444-2 (net.rim.browser.tools.widget 2.5.1.201010291444-2)

To: bundle org.eclipse.ui.views [3.5.0,3.6.0)

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.4.1.20110909-1818 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.20110909-1818)

To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK]

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group

3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK)

```
To: org.eclipse.ui.views [3.6.0.I20110412-0800]"Arsenal")');
```

can anyone tell me who has done this before how to add blackberry webworks plugin in eclipse