# plugin for blackberry app using phonegap

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am confused which plugin to install

1-http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web--blackberry webworks sdk and plugin
2-http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java--blackberry java plugin and sdk

First plugin was not getting installed so I installed second one but didn't know where to place html,js pages.
Here http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks  ,it was written to install first plugin so is it not possible to use html pages with second plugin as first plugin was not getting installed .I have mentioned the problem with plugin here [cannot install blackberry webworks plugin in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683868/cannot-install-blackberry-webworks-plugin-in-eclipse)